# Javascript recognize random choice from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I have an array that chooses one of three colors at random every time the function runs. How could I make Javascript identify the random color choice as the same variable every time the function runs.

I'm not really sure where to start with this so this is what I have:

```
var colors = ['#ce0e0e', '#079b0c', '#3e3fd6'];

function changeColor(){
 myDiv.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}
```

Do I need to add an ID into the div and then do something like:

```
var randomColor = document.getElementById('colorAtRandom');
```

Comment: Just add it in the changeColor() function, or even better, split it into generateColor() and changeStyle() Since you already generate the color in the script, there's no use in looking at the element in the DOM again to get it's color.

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Could you expand on "make Javascript identify the random color choice"? 
Do you mean output it to the page or just store it in a variable?

Comment: Jonas Wilms, I would like to be able to use that information later in the site, for example, if I wanted to change something else to the same color at a different time.

Comment: redreddington, by "make Javascript identify the random color choice", I mean have a variable of sorts be linked to that random color from the array. But so the variable changes every time a new coor from the array is chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a while statement that checks if the random color selected is the same as the color currently used. Once it is true you can again set the color to a random color. This will happen until there is a color selected that is not already used.

This should work.

```js
var colors = ['#ce0e0e', '#079b0c', '#3e3fd6'];

function changeColor(){
  var randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  while (myDiv.style.backgroundColor == randomColor) //if color is alredy being used
   randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]; // get a new color
 
  //if new color is found set color
  myDiv.style.backgroundColor = randomColor;
}
```